# "hg" directory location on Hostgator Mercurial Installation

Tags: mercurial, shared-hosting

I am following the directions [here](http://blog.tlensing.org/2010/04/12/installing-mercurial-on-a-shared-web-server-without-root-access-hosteurope/) trying to get Mercurial running on my shared HostGator account.

I am supposed to create a "hg" directory, but I am unsure if it is to be in the /home/user/ location or in /home/user/domain-I-want-to-version-control/. I actually tried creating that directory, and the modified 'index.cgi' inside. When I then navigate to (url)/hg I get an internal server error.

Could really use some guidance, please.

Answer (score 1):

Never create repository this way! If you want to add Mercurial repo for existing code (did you try to verify, that you have **working hg**?!) read before it [QuickStart Guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/QuickStart#Setting_up_a_new_Mercurial_project) at least

Comment: I 'verified' by executing 'hg' in the console, and I got the help dialogue. I have looked at the documentation that you have linked me to, but it is mostly all over my head.

I have close to zero understanding of what I'm doing with this stuff. I am just (trying) to follow the tutorial linked above so that I can build sites on localhost or live on the server.

Any help in any way will be very much appreciated.